# Get image form folder and store in feature image directly code

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm looking to see if a plugin exists that will allow me to select a folder with images already in it so that it could randomly create a featured image for new posts unless otherwise specified in the post.

For example...Let's say you have a blog featuring strawberries. And all your posts have to do with strawberries. You have a folder with 150 different strawberry pictures...so this theoretical plugin would randomly pick one of those images unless in the post you specify that you want to manually select or upload a different image...ie, you have a post about blueberries and thus, a strawberry picture wouldn't be appropriate.

Does such a plugin exist?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just give the images a sequential name, say from 1.png to 150.png and then pick one up randomly using rand() ?

Do you really need a plugin for this?